# Web scraping client certificate issue WinHttp - excel VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, winhttp

So, I'm trying to scrape the following public site using vba and the `WinHttp` library:

https://auctions.seecao.com/DAILY_AUCTION_LIST

Having examined the network traffic when the "Show Data" button is clicked, I came up with my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim border As String
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim url As String
Dim reqBodyObj As Object, respObj As Object, auction As Object
Dim reqBodyStr As String
Dim deliveryDay As Date
url = "https://auctions.seecao.com/api/DailyAuction/GetDailyAuctionList"
deliveryDay = Date
border = "ALME"
Set reqBodyObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""parameters"":{""dayFrom"":""2021-04-01"",""dayTill"":""2021-04-01"",""auctionState"":[0,3,4,5,6,7,9]}}")
reqBodyObj("parameters")("dayFrom") = Format(deliveryDay + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
reqBodyObj("parameters")("dayTill") = Format(deliveryDay + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
reqBodyStr = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(reqBodyObj)

With req
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = 256 '=0x0100 =ignore "Unknown certification authority (CA) or untrusted root" error refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequestoption
    .send reqBodyStr
    Debug.Print .responseText
    Set respObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With

For Each auction In respObj("dailyAuctionListData")("rows")
    If auction("columns")("auctionName") Like border & "*" Then
        Debug.Print auction("columns")("id")
    End If
Next auction
End Sub
```

It's probably worth noting that the first time you visit the site via a browser you'll get a warning saying that the server's certificate is not trusted and you'll have to add an exception to visit it:

[image]

To overcome this I used this `.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = 256` to ignore the errors.

**Everything worked fine** for about a month. Today however I started getting the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147012711 (80072f99)': No credentials were available
> in the client certificate.

So I suppose that the website started requesting a client certificate?

Requesting the data through a browser works normally without the need of any credentials and the `POST` request that is being sent under the hood seems to be the same as it used to be. Editing and resending the request via the browser's developer tools also works without any problems.

So my question is, what is going on here? Is the site asking for a client certificate?

And if so, which client certificate does Firefox use under the hood?

Does the browser use some kind of a default certificate for these cases?

Why am I asked for credentials when I run the code when clearly they are not needed when I visit the page?

Finally, when I try to specify a random certificate like so :

`.SetClientCertificate "NameOfCertificate"`

the request is being sent and I get the following response:

```html
<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that it's a public site accessible to everyone. No subscription needed.

**EDIT**

The same request works just fine with `Postman` after disabling SSL certificate verification. Is there a way to imitate this behavior in VBA?

Comment: What brand is "the browser"? WinHttpRequest uses the installed IE. Did you try accessing the page with IE or with another browser?

Comment: @StureS It doesn't really have to do with the browser. Yes I've tried 3 of them. Getting the data via browser works, getting it via HTTP request doesn't.

Comment: Exactly my point! Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: @StureS If what you're asking is whether I tried using an `InternetExplorer` object to basically automate the browser instead of sending HTTP requests then no I haven't and I'd like to avoid it. That's not the intent of my question. I want to understand what is actually going on under the hood. Thank you though.

Comment: "under the hood" is IE operating your requests. Use IE manually to determine if it behaves equally!

Comment: @StureS As I said, I **have** used IE manually along with 2 other browsers. And **no** IE is **not** running under the hood when I'm building and sending an HTTP request from scratch. That's the point of doing that.

Comment: Then please, what browser is running under the hood in Microsoft VBA then?

Comment: Would you please ask yourself what software and logic is handling the HTTP(S) requests? Is it Google's Chrome? Is it Firefox?  ...

Comment: Would somebody please advise Stavros that the software running when using *Microsoft WinHttp Services*  is not an entirely new software from Microsoft but is a subset of IE.

Comment: Can you download certificates then add path as e.g. [here](https://microsoft.public.xml.narkive.com/Y6hHVF79/msxml-posting-soap-message-with-client-certificate) ?

Comment: @QHarr I was really hoping you would show up! :) The thing is, I don't know if a certificate is actually needed and even if it is I have no idea which one would it be. I only have a couple of them in the "Personal" store and they are completely irrelevant as they are intended to be used with other sites. What confuses me is that neither any of the browsers I've used nor Postman need any client certificates. I've edited and resent the request via dev tools without problems. Plus this is completely public and there's no need for credentials. Could you possibly try the code and see if it fails?

Comment: Sure though I tried a copy of the request copied from dev tools in python -giving http 500

Comment: @QHarr maybe it has to do with the "Unknown certification authority (CA) or untrusted root" error which I'm suppressing using  `.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags) = 256`? In Postman I had to disable SSL Verification and then it worked perfectly. VBA was working perfectly as well up until today.

Comment: Oops. I lied! It works fine in python with verifying set to false

Comment: @QHarr Yeah...Server's certificate was a problem from the begining and I dealt with it by ignoring it. The client side though and the `No credentials were available in the client certificate.` error is new and it started today. Thanks so much for your time!! let me know if you come up with anything.

Comment: So the difference for me was my anti-virus. Once I allowed that to permit the insecure request then your code ran fine.

Comment: @QHarr hmm I will have to try that on my personal PC then. So the antivirus is blocking excel but not Postman or the browsers themselves?

Comment: my anti-virus blocked browser as well IIRC

Comment: @QHarr Nope, no luck. Tried it on a personal machine with no antivirus whatsoever and it doesn't work. However, I'm now getting the `400 Bad request SSL error` instead of the `No credentials were available in the client certificate.` one. Postman is still running just fine. I don't understand...:(

Comment: I need to work out what my anti-virus software does (security software - not just anti-virus). It temporarily allowed your code to run. Now, several hours later it prompted me to allow again before your code would run again.

Comment: @QHarr BTW...Do you think it could somehow be related to the fact that this API is using TLSv1.3?

Comment: I dunno. Possibly. The problem I have at the moment is I need to wait until whatever my protection centre did to expire so I can test my latest thoughts :-(